# Remove Item from ListView in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to remove the list item from the list view using a delete button in the list. The delete button is must for my application.

The data is stored in an `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`, so when I click the delete button the data in the array list is removed of that particular position and then `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called. But after this I got an **index out of bound exception** as there is only one item in my list view.

Please let me know that how can I stop my application from crashing and showing an empty list when the data is removed.

This is my code Please have a look.

```
View vi = convertView;
if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification_list, null);
        TextView name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.NotifScreenName);
        TextView message = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.NotifScreenText);
        TextView time = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.NotifScreenTime);
        ImageView image = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.NotifScreenPic);
        Button accept = (Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.NotifScreenAccept);
        Button decline = (Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.NotifScreenDecline);
        name.setText(data.get(position).get("name"));
        message.setText(data.get(position).get("text"));
        long dv = Long.valueOf(data.get(position).get("sentTime"))*1000;
        Date df = new java.util.Date(dv);
        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, hh:mm a").format(df);
        time.setText(date);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(data.get(position).get("image"), image);
        accept.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        decline.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                data.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

This is the Logcat Output:

```
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at com.pnf.myevent.ListAdapter.getView(ListAdapter.java:95)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2143)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1320)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:985)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:985)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:985)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-12 11:04:32.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post your logcat, so that the reason your app is crashing can be learnt

Comment: @onkar Please check the logcat...

Comment: this line data.remove(position); data is empy check before remove is empty or not ok!

Comment: my code is removing the data but I am getting this exception on the notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @Abhishek Try my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if data is empty before you call `data.remove(position)` in the onClickListener of your decline variable.

Edit: It should be data.get(position) where you should be making your checks that is when you are creating your view.

Comment: my code is removing the data but I am getting this exception on the notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: check if data is empty before you are calling data.get(position) and all other accesses to data..

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
data.remove(position-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar but using onContextItemSelected.

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    AdapterContextMenuInfo aInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    planetsList.remove(aInfo.position)
    aAdpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return true;
}
```

Where planetList is an ArrayList and aAdpt is my custom adapter.
You can have more information on my blog [here](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listviewarrayadapter-and.html) and [here](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/09/listviewpart-1.html).
Hope this help you.